# How to make a web based drag and drop form builder?

Tags: javascript, django, frontend

I wanted a general direction on what tools/technologies to use to build a simple web-based form builder (I have seen the jquery post, that's not what I'm looking for). I was thinking reactjs/vuejs but I need to know if it's possible before I commit to one toolset as opposed to another.

Just to reiterate, my requirement is "build a web-based form builder, people can use it to build forms (like banks/DMVs) and share them with their clients so they can be filled online and printed or printed and filled offline". How would I start implementing it? (already settled on django for backend, I just need recommendations for implementing that functionality in the frontend) Thanks :)

Comment: I think almost the entire main form building feature of this application will have to be manually coded in. What React and Vue can do is just aid you in the rendering and updating the interface. Vue is pretty easy to pick up, haven't used React at all. I do think this post belongs more to `reddit.com/r/webdev` than SO though. This post does give me some personal project idea though :-D

Comment: Ah, thanks, I just needed to know where to start. And I've thought about doing everything manually but before I did I just wanted to make sure there wasn't  some method/framework I'm missing.  I'll probably post it on reddit too. Glad it gave you a project idea!

Comment: @Morpheus.47 have you managed to get this work by using react js, If so what library or plugins you have used for drag and drop.

Answer (score 1):

https://shopify.github.io/draggable/ looks like a good, modern library. And it is developed/supported by Shopify, so there is some credibility behind it.